# Как вывести числа, а не символы?

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Есть задание:

В заданном массиве чисел определить номера чисел, не входящих в другой массив.

Мне кажется, я уже близок, но столкнулся с одной проблемой: когда вывожу результат в окно, вместо чисел получаю символы, а мне нужны номера элементов массива!

```
    .486
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\macros\macros.asm
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
.data

stroka db '35622379',0
zagol db 'Marina',0
lens=$-stroka
podst db '31684332',0
lenq=$-podst
itog dw lens dup (0),0

.code

start:
cld
mov ebx, 0
mov esi, 0
cycl:
mov ecx, lens
lea edi, podst
mov al, stroka[esi]
inc si
repne scasb
je cycl
mov itog[ebx],si
inc ebx
inc si
cmp si, lens
jle cycl

found:
invoke MessageBox,0,addr itog,addr zagol,0

exit: 
invoke ExitProcess, 0

end start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не знаю ассемблер, но я отвечу!:)

На мой взгляд в вашей программе несколько багов.

Например значение `lens` включает в себя также строку 'Marina'.

Я думаю, что вместо этого

```
stroka db '35622379',0
zagol db 'Marina',0
lens=$-stroka
```

вы имели в виду это

```
stroka db '35622379',0
lens=$-stroka
zagol db 'Marina',0
```

Далее, у вас два раза увеличивается `si`

```
inc si ; тут
repne scasb
je cycl
mov itog[ebx],si
inc ebx
inc si ; и тут
```

Мне представляется, что второе увеличение регистра `si` ошибочно.

К тому же так как вы увеличиваете `si` перед записью в `itog` то у вас индексация будет идти с 1, а не с 0 в итоговом результате.

И, наконец, MessageBox выводит символьные строки, а массив `itog` не содержит символы. Он содержит числа.

Чтобы вывести числа, то вам нужно преобразовать их в символы. Возможно, что вполне достаточно к каждому слову прибавить символ '0' И выводить на экран нужно не слова, а байты и желательно с разделителями в виде пробела или запятой.

Comment: Да, с ошибками вы были правы, а с выводом вместо символов чисел, достаточно прибавить 30h к нашему числу, тогда в таблице символов мы опустимся на 4 ряд где числа) только это будет работать с числами до 9, но мне достаточно, вопрос закрыт